# How to sum the numbers of a column in a secondary table with SQL

Tags: sql

I have a Table Owners

Owner  product

```
Jhon    product1

Jhon    product2

Jhon    product3

Chris   product4
```

Another Table: Products

Product   QuantitySold

```
Product1  3

Product2  5

Product3  2

Product4  7
```

How do I do a SQL to come up with the following result:

1. Name of Owner
2. Number of products
3. QuantitySold

   NameOfOwner    NumberOfProducts    QuantitySold

   Jhon                         3                                     10 (3+5+2)

   Chris                        1                                     7

I tried:

```
select Owners.owner, count(distinct Owners.product) as NumberOfProducts, sum(Product.QuantitySold) as QuantitySold from Owners O, Products P

group by O.owner
```

But that returns the total of quantitySold for any owner (17 = 3+5+2+7) multiple by the number of products.

```
NameOfOwner    NumberOfProducts    QuantitySold

Jhon                         3      51 = 3 * 17 (3+5+2+7)

Chris                        1      17 = 1 * 17 (3+5+2+7)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a inner join (or other kind of join):

```
select owner, count(a.product) nr_of_products, sum(quantity) Qnt_Sold from Owners inner join Products on Owners.product = Products.product group by owner
```

Different SQL JOINs:

**INNER JOIN**: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables

**LEFT JOIN**: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table

**RIGHT JOIN**: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table

**FULL JOIN**: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.Name, count(o.Name) NumberOfProducts, sum(QuantitySold) QuantitySold from #Owner o inner join #Product p on p.Name=o.Product
Group By o.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.owner as NameOfOwner, count(a.Product) as NumberOfProducts,sum(QuantitySold) as QuantitySold from Owners as a 
INNER JOIN Products on a.Product = Products.Product group by a.owner
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much a repeat here of the other answers, but including a run on [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3a8c/7).

```
SELECT o.owner as Owner, count(o.owner) as NumberofProducts, sum(p.quantitySold) as Quantity
FROM Owners o
inner Join Products p
on o.product = p.product
Group by o.owner
```